# Why is this material so resource heavy, and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: materials

[image]

This is a forged composite material I made, but it makes blender lag, especially when I zoom in. What is making this particular material so resource heavy, and how can I fix it?

Comment: 5 (perlin) noise nodes are pretty heavy. Can you achieve something similar with a single noise node with the detail turned up?

Comment: To follow up on @RonJensen.. Noise is expensive, and all your noises are 4D.. you can only see 2 of the dimensions. 1 2D noise, put through mapping nodes to shift and scale? The 'Roughness', etc, doesn't vary much, so you're probably not losing anything, that way...

Comment: Definitely agree that reducing the dimensions of the Noise will drastically improve performance. In this case it looks like 3D noise should be sufficient (eg, UV on X and Y, leaving Z to take the place of the 4D ‘W’ input).